# Firefox Defining Date Wrong with new Date().getTime();

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, utc

I'm defining a variable, data.EndTimeUTC which has a value of "2015-10-09T18:15:00"

Using Javascript, I'm converting that to milliseconds using...

```
var liveTime = new Date(data.EndTimeUTC).getTime();
```

In all browsers, it's giving the right answer; 1444414500000 but for whatever reason, Firefox is giving 1444425300000 which is exactly 3 hours off.

Any ideas what's going on there? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Timezone is probably killing you.

Comment: That's what I'm kind of wondering - except the time that I'm getting from the server is the time in GMT - it SHOULD be running independent of timezones - which is the case in all browsers, except Firefox. Could Firefox be somehow trying to account for our 3 hour offset from GMT?

Comment: It's definitely NOT independent in the browser.  When you create time, it's based on the timezone the browser believe's it's in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

`var liveTime = Date.UTC(2015, 9, 9, 18, 15, 0)`

For your case:

```
var fixedUTC = data.EndTimeUTC + "Z";

var liveTime = Date.parse(fixedUTC);
```

Comment: Ok, so, that technically works. How do I get from "2015-10-09T18:15:00" to "2015, 9, 9, 18, 15, 0"?

Comment: I'm sure there's more elegant solutions out there, but this brute force has worked for me.  I just wish javascript and .NET would play nice one day with dates.

Comment: Firefox, hilariously, is giving me NaN on Date.parse(fixedUTC);

Chrome is fine. I don't get it.

Comment: Try `var fixedUTC = data.EndTimeUTC + 'Z';` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `T` with `' '` and `-` with `/` which makes new string working for different browser.
Below code is working fine for Chrome and Firefox as tested:

```js
var date1 = '2015-10-09T18:15:00';
date1 = date1.replace('T', ' ');
var time = new Date(date1.replace(/-/g,'/')).getTime();
alert(time);
```